# Selecting <a> tag in CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to format the following code (HTML part).

```css
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

a.buttons {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: padding 1s;
}

a.buttons:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="http://linkto.bandcamp.com">Bandcamp</a>
<a href="C:\Users\asdffds\Desktop\website\management.html">Booking</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
</div>
```

But I can't seem to get it work. Can someone help find the mistake?

Comment: This is a *very* basic CSS question that you could've easily solved by looking for introductory HTML and CSS tutorials.

Comment: i'm a total noob, sorry

Comment: Everybody was, some day. But we expect you to do some research before you ask questions and this could easily be solved by looking online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
.buttons a{

 }

.buttons a:hover{

 }
```

Comment: It is the `div` element which has the `buttons` class, not the `a`elements, so you need the selector @BinaryBuilder has posted.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
a.buttons {

}
```

you are telling add style to all class with name **button** inside **a** tag. Which is actually other way around. So it should be:

```
.buttons a {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the button css with the code below. Since anchor tags are inside a div with class buttons, we need to target anchor tags with its parent container i.e div.buttons

```
.buttons a {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: padding 1s;
}

.buttons a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

And use relative paths to the links, as I can see some links pointing to your c drive. For example you can redirect to \management.html if that html is present in your root directory.